# How to implement get directions in gmaps4rails

Tags: google-maps-api-3, gmaps4rails

How to I implement a feature like this,
http://www.chalo.pk/places/YMA-Body-Building-Gym/cFEfq

Please open the site and click get directions.

Any ideas are welcome.

Comment: See http://apneadiving.github.io

Comment: @apneadiving I have already implemented your gem to show markers from geocoded data from the database. Imagine this, I open up a page and I get a map of Paris because I have the long, lat of Paris. And say I am in New York , how to I calculate the distance or direction and show it on the map.

Comment: Check the link, there ia a directiona example